# Why does Eclipse IDE put code folding markers on a statement that has nothing to fold?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, folding

I'm having an issue with Eclipse folding javascript code improperly and I have no idea what the problem is. I'm in the process of building a game engine so I have a particular object constructor followed by a function that calculates framerate:

```
function Constructor() {
    //A whole bunch of code for this constructor

    this.method = function() {
        //A bunch of method code
        this.context.font = "blahblah";
    };
}

function calculateFrameRate(times) {
    //All the code for calculating framerate
}
```

For whatever reason, it gives me the option to fold starting at the context.font statement, and it collapses all the way through the framerate calculating function. This obviously is not a valid block of code to collapse. Any ideas as to what the problem could be?

Comment: This is a bug in eclipse's JavaScript editor. Your code is not at fault.

Comment: This post was made a long time ago. What version of Eclipse was the bug reproducible in?

Answer (score 0):

try naming the function in `this.method = function() {` to be something like `this.method = function method() {`